# Mac: How to load Postgres Example Database using Postgress.app

Tags: macos, postgresql

I just downloaded the Postgres.app (9.4.5). I want to load (restore) the example database from http://postgresguide.com/setup/example.html. I can't seem to get it imported.

I opened a psql session via the app, exited back to the shell, created a .bash_profile in my home directory (per http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html), quit terminal and opened a new psql session and exited to the shell once again. I then ran the pg_restore command as shown on the example page. I saved the log, but it is 3K lines long and doesn't show any obvious errors. There is nothing in the pgadmin.log in my home directory.

When I start pgAdmin3, I can find no evidence that the database was loaded.

I'm brand new to Postgres, but experienced with Oracle and MySQL.

This is all I see in pgAdmin3. I created the one table in my schema manually.

Did I overlook something?

[image: pgAdmin3 Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pg_restore command on that page does NOT restore the database. It dumps the contents of the backup to stdout. It needs an additional switch '-d' to import directly into a database. But first you have to create an empty database. You can do that from pgAdmin lets say you call it exampledb then the restore would become:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d exampledb  example.dump
```

Comment: Thanks, Eelke. Not sure why the listed those options for a stdout dump, especially hostname.